# Add arbitrary string to URLs in Rails/Middleman app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleman

I'm using middleman to generate a static webpage. I need to add a consistent but understandable string to all urls so I can understand how users navigate on the page.
Now i do it like this

```
<% link_to '/'+?button=navigation , class: 'logotype', itemprop: 'url' do %> 
  ...
<% end %>
```

I would prefer not having to manually add all the parameters but rather just use something that's already there, like a scope or something. I was thinking about using the name of the template file for example. The url is not unique enough.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you making static pages with a rails app? Unless it is only 1 static page...

Comment: What string are you adding here? `'?button=navigation`? That's not valid Ruby in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing this would be to write a helper method that encapsulates your functionality:

```
 <%= link_to_as_nav('/', class: 'logotype', ...) do %>
   ...
 <% end %>
```

Then write a helper method:

```
 def link_to_as_nav(url, options)
    link_to(url + '?button=navigation', options)
 end
```

This is the naïve approach and won't account for a `url` argument that already has parameters added, but that's something you can work to fix.